# Printer takes more than one page

Tags: printer

I have HP Printer Deskjet F2280, some times when I print it takes more than one page and prints on multiple pages...How can I fix it?

the type is plain paper A4 and I don't have any other options

Comment: What are you printing that does this, versus what doesn't do it?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I print

Comment: So, you're saying you can print the same document twice in a row, and once it will do this and once it won't?  Yeah, sounds like a mechanical issue, I'm with @DaveM.

Answer (score 5):

There are some factors that can cause this.  If the air is dry, the paper will often stick.  It is why many printer makers suggest "fanning" the paper before loading.  Some paper is more prone to this.

The pickup rollers will also get smooth after use and then they slip slightly and will grab more than one sheet.  These may need replacing or a treatment with a product called "rubber renew".